# How to automatically rename files while unzipping from dired-mode on OSX

Tags: emacs, elisp, unzip

I would like to automatically rename files (if they already exist in the destination directory) while unzipping archives from dired-mode on OSX (10.6.8 Snow Leopard).  Is there a way to feed `unzip` a letter `r` for `rename` under-the-hood every time a `replace [filename]` prompt occurs under-the-hood?  Or, is there a better method?

Based on the OSX built-in `unzip --help` dialog, there does not appear to be a command-line option to automatically rename files if they already exist.  Instead, this is a terminal interactive dialog that occurs while `unzip` is functioning [e.g., `replace test.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename`].  This behavior is the same whether I use `dired-do-compress` or my own function with `start-process . . .`

<strike>I'm not fond of `Archive Utility.app` because it is visible while unzipping and then it takes me to the destination folder in Finder.app.  I'd prefer to stay in Emacs, and not have to use an Applescript to take me back there, or have to manually switch back after closing the Finder.app window.</strike>

**EDIT** (July 8, 2014):  Archive Utility.app has user preferences that can be set by directly opening the application located at:  `/System/Library/CoreServices/Archive Utility.app`  Preferences include, but are not limited to, whether to reveal expanded item(s) in Finder.app

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/archive_utility_preferences.png))</sub>

---

Unzip option #1:  `M-x dired-do-compress`

```
(eval-after-load "dired-aux"
   '(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-suffixes 
                 '("\\.zip\\'" ".zip" "unzip")))
```

---

Unzip option # 2:  Either use `unzip` that comes with OSX; or use, `Archive Utility.app`

```
(defun lawlist-zip-unzip ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
    (lawlist-filename (file-name-nondirectory (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
    (archive-filename (file-name-nondirectory (concat (file-name-sans-extension lawlist-filename) ".zip")))
    (archive (dired-get-file-for-visit))
    (unarchive-utility "/System/Library/CoreServices/Archive Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Archive Utility"))
    (message "[z]ip | [u]nzip")
    (let* ((zip-or-unzip (read-char-exclusive)))
      (cond
        ((eq zip-or-unzip ?z)
          (when (and lawlist-filename (file-exists-p archive-filename))
            (or (y-or-n-p (format "File `%s' exists; overwrite? "archive-filename))
              (error "Canceled")))
          (start-process "zip-file" nil "zip" archive-filename lawlist-filename))
        ((eq zip-or-unzip ?u)
          (start-process "unzip-file" nil "unzip" archive)
          ;; (start-process "unzip-file" nil unarchive-utility archive)
        )))
    (sit-for .5)
    (revert-buffer)))
```

---

Error message:

```
Compress or uncompress test.zip? (y or n)  y
Uncompressing /Users/HOME/Desktop/test.zip...
unzip ("/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.zip")
Archive:  /Users/HOME/Desktop/test.zip
replace test.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
(assuming [N]one)
Failed to compress/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.zip
```

---

`unzip` help dialog:

```
MP:~ HOME$ unzip --help
UnZip 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
  -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment
  -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir

modifiers:                                   -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
  -n  never overwrite existing files         -a  auto-convert any text files
  -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -aa treat ALL files as text
  -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -v  be verbose/print version info
  -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
  -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
  -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
Examples (see unzip.txt for more info):
  unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
  unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
  unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
```

Comment: Dig through `unzip`'s source (if it's open) and try to find which flag is set when the user interactively sets `[y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one` and then see if there can be made any connection between that and the command line arguments `unzip` is sent. If so, exploit it.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, here is a related thread from the unzip forum:  http://www.info-zip.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to obtain Unzip version 6.0 with the `-B` option enabled -- **[UNIXBACKUP compile option enabled] Save a backup copy of each overwritten file in foo~ or foo~99999 format.**

```
MP:~ HOME$ /tmp/unzip --hh

Extended Help for UnZip

See the UnZip Manual for more detailed help


UnZip lists and extracts files in zip archives.  The default action is to
extract zipfile entries to the current directory, creating directories as
needed.  With appropriate options, UnZip lists the contents of archives
instead.

Basic unzip command line:
  unzip [-Z] options archive[.zip] [file ...] [-x xfile ...] [-d exdir]

Some examples:
  unzip -l foo.zip        - list files in short format in archive foo.zip

  unzip -t foo            - test the files in archive foo

  unzip -Z foo            - list files using more detailed zipinfo format

  unzip foo               - unzip the contents of foo in current dir

  unzip -a foo            - unzip foo and convert text files to local OS

If unzip is run in zipinfo mode, a more detailed list of archive contents
is provided.  The -Z option sets zipinfo mode and changes the available
options.

Basic zipinfo command line:
  zipinfo options archive[.zip] [file ...] [-x xfile ...]
  unzip -Z options archive[.zip] [file ...] [-x xfile ...]

Below, Mac OS refers to Mac OS before Mac OS X.  Mac OS X is a Unix based
port and is referred to as Unix Apple.


unzip options:
  -Z   Switch to zipinfo mode.  Must be first option.
  -hh  Display extended help.
  -A   [OS/2, Unix DLL] Print extended help for DLL.
  -c   Extract files to stdout/screen.  As -p but include names.  Also,
         -a allowed and EBCDIC conversions done if needed.
  -f   Freshen by extracting only if older file on disk.
  -l   List files using short form.
  -p   Extract files to pipe (stdout).  Only file data is output and all
         files extracted in binary mode (as stored).
  -t   Test archive files.
  -T   Set timestamp on archive(s) to that of newest file.  Similar to
       zip -o but faster.
  -u   Update existing older files on disk as -f and extract new files.
  -v   Use verbose list format.  If given alone as unzip -v show version
         information.  Also can be added to other list commands for more
         verbose output.
  -z   Display only archive comment.

unzip modifiers:
  -a   Convert text files to local OS format.  Convert line ends, EOF
         marker, and from or to EBCDIC character set as needed.
  -b   Treat all files as binary.  [Tandem] Force filecode 180 ('C').
         [VMS] Autoconvert binary files.  -bb forces convert of all files.
  -B   [UNIXBACKUP compile option enabled] Save a backup copy of each
         overwritten file in foo~ or foo~99999 format.
  -C   Use case-insensitive matching.
  -D   Skip restoration of timestamps for extracted directories.  On VMS this
         is on by default and -D essentially becames -DD.
  -DD  Skip restoration of timestamps for all entries.
  -E   [MacOS (not Unix Apple)]  Display contents of MacOS extra field during
         restore.
  -F   [Acorn] Suppress removal of NFS filetype extension.  [Non-Acorn if
         ACORN_FTYPE_NFS] Translate filetype and append to name.
  -i   [MacOS] Ignore filenames in MacOS extra field.  Instead, use name in
         standard header.
  -j   Junk paths and deposit all files in extraction directory.
  -J   [BeOS] Junk file attributes.  [MacOS] Ignore MacOS specific info.
  -K   [AtheOS, BeOS, Unix] Restore SUID/SGID/Tacky file attributes.
  -L   Convert to lowercase any names from uppercase only file system.
  -LL  Convert all files to lowercase.
  -M   Pipe all output through internal pager similar to Unix more(1).
  -n   Never overwrite existing files.  Skip extracting that file, no prompt.
  -N   [Amiga] Extract file comments as Amiga filenotes.
  -o   Overwrite existing files without prompting.  Useful with -f.  Use with
         care.
  -P p Use password p to decrypt files.  THIS IS INSECURE!  Some OS show
         command line to other users.
  -q   Perform operations quietly.  The more q (as in -qq) the quieter.
  -s   [OS/2, NT, MS-DOS] Convert spaces in filenames to underscores.
  -S   [VMS] Convert text files (-a, -aa) into Stream_LF format.
  -U   [UNICODE enabled] Show non-local characters as #Uxxxx or #Lxxxxxx ASCII
         text escapes where x is hex digit.  [Old] -U used to leave names
         uppercase if created on MS-DOS, VMS, etc.  See -L.
  -UU  [UNICODE enabled] Disable use of stored UTF-8 paths.  Note that UTF-8
         paths stored as native local paths are still processed as Unicode.
  -V   Retain VMS file version numbers.
  -W   [Only if WILD_STOP_AT_DIR] Modify pattern matching so ? and * do not
         match directory separator /, but ** does.  Allows matching at specific
         directory levels.
  -X   [VMS, Unix, OS/2, NT, Tandem] Restore UICs and ACL entries under VMS,
         or UIDs/GIDs under Unix, or ACLs under certain network-enabled
         versions of OS/2, or security ACLs under Windows NT.  Can require
         user privileges.
  -XX  [NT] Extract NT security ACLs after trying to enable additional
         system privileges.
  -Y   [VMS] Treat archived name endings of .nnn as VMS version numbers.
  -$   [MS-DOS, OS/2, NT] Restore volume label if extraction medium is
         removable.  -$$ allows fixed media (hard drives) to be labeled.
  -/ e [Acorn] Use e as extension list.
  -:   [All but Acorn, VM/CMS, MVS, Tandem] Allow extract archive members into
         locations outside of current extraction root folder.  This allows
         paths such as ../foo to be extracted above the current extraction
         directory, which can be a security problem.
  -^   [Unix] Allow control characters in names of extracted entries.  Usually
         this is not a good thing and should be avoided.
  -2   [VMS] Force unconditional conversion of names to ODS-compatible names.
         Default is to exploit destination file system, preserving cases and
         extended name characters on ODS5 and applying ODS2 filtering on ODS2.


Wildcards:
  Internally unzip supports the following wildcards:
    ?       (or %% or #, depending on OS) matches any single character
    *       matches any number of characters, including zero
    [list]  matches char in list (regex), can do range [ac-f], all but [!bf]
  If port supports [], must escape [ as [[]
  For shells that expand wildcards, escape (\* or "*") so unzip can recurse.

Include and Exclude:
  -i pattern pattern ...   include files that match a pattern
  -x pattern pattern ...   exclude files that match a pattern
  Patterns are paths with optional wildcards and match paths as stored in
  archive.  Exclude and include lists end at next option or end of line.
    unzip archive -x pattern pattern ...

Multi-part (split) archives (archives created as a set of split files):
  Currently split archives are not readable by unzip.  A workaround is
  to use zip to convert the split archive to a single-file archive and
  use unzip on that.  See the manual page for Zip 3.0 or later.

Streaming (piping into unzip):
  Currently unzip does not support streaming.  The funzip utility can be
  used to process the first entry in a stream.
    cat archive | funzip

Testing archives:
  -t        test contents of archive
  This can be modified using -q for quieter operation, and -qq for even
  quieter operation.

Unicode:
  If compiled with Unicode support, unzip automatically handles archives
  with Unicode entries.  Currently Unicode on Win32 systems is limited.
  Characters not in the current character set are shown as ASCII escapes
  in the form #Uxxxx where the Unicode character number fits in 16 bits,
  or #Lxxxxxx where it doesn't, where x is the ASCII character for a hex
  digit.


zipinfo options (these are used in zipinfo mode (unzip -Z ...)):
  -1  List names only, one per line.  No headers/trailers.  Good for scripts.
  -2  List names only as -1, but include headers, trailers, and comments.
  -s  List archive entries in short Unix ls -l format.  Default list format.
  -m  List in long Unix ls -l format.  As -s, but includes compression %.
  -l  List in long Unix ls -l format.  As -m, but compression in bytes.
  -v  List zipfile information in verbose, multi-page format.
  -h  List header line.  Includes archive name, actual size, total files.
  -M  Pipe all output through internal pager similar to Unix more(1) command.
  -t  List totals for files listed or for all files.  Includes uncompressed
        and compressed sizes, and compression factors.
  -T  Print file dates and times in a sortable decimal format (yymmdd.hhmmss)
        Default date and time format is a more human-readable version.
  -U  [UNICODE] If entry has a UTF-8 Unicode path, display any characters
        not in current character set as text #Uxxxx and #Lxxxxxx escapes
        representing the Unicode character number of the character in hex.
  -UU [UNICODE]  Disable use of any UTF-8 path information.
  -z  Include archive comment if any in listing.


funzip stream extractor:
  funzip extracts the first member in an archive to stdout.  Typically
  used to unzip the first member of a stream or pipe.  If a file argument
  is given, read from that file instead of stdin.

funzip command line:
  funzip [-password] [input[.zip|.gz]]


unzipsfx self extractor:
  Self-extracting archives made with unzipsfx are no more (or less)
  portable across different operating systems than unzip executables.
  In general, a self-extracting archive made on a particular Unix system,
  for example, will only self-extract under the same flavor of Unix.
  Regular unzip may still be used to extract embedded archive however.

unzipsfx command line:
  <unzipsfx+archive_filename>  [-options] [file(s) ... [-x xfile(s) ...]]

unzipsfx options:
  -c, -p - Output to pipe.  (See above for unzip.)
  -f, -u - Freshen and Update, as for unzip.
  -t     - Test embedded archive.  (Can be used to list contents.)
  -z     - Print archive comment.  (See unzip above.)

unzipsfx modifiers:
  Most unzip modifiers are supported.  These include
  -a     - Convert text files.
  -n     - Never overwrite.
  -o     - Overwrite without prompting.
  -q     - Quiet operation.
  -C     - Match names case-insensitively.
  -j     - Junk paths.
  -V     - Keep version numbers.
  -s     - Convert spaces to underscores.
  -$     - Restore volume label.

If unzipsfx compiled with SFX_EXDIR defined, -d option also available:
  -d exd - Extract to directory exd.
By default, all files extracted to current directory.  This option
forces extraction to specified directory.

See unzipsfx manual page for more information.
```